# Semantic information in AST

Tags: compiler-construction, control-flow

Suppose we have classic Abstract Syntax Tree of a program. I wonder worth it to put purely semantic information (referred variable type, size in bytes, etc) in AST? I need all this stuff for different types of analysis. So having this, I guess, allows us to have all this information in muptiple analyzers, every of which works as single AST traversal and not depends on others. But on the other hand, syntax and semantic information is now stored in one place.

Another way is to keep AST minimal, representing only syntax details. But then it force us to do same things (maintain symbol tables, etc) in different analyzers.

P.S. Meaning analyzer I'm talking about variable usage, type, control flow analysis.

For example, Clang puts implicit (not really syntax) information such as type conversions into its AST:

```c
`-FunctionDecl 0x5aeab50 <test.cc:1:1, line:4:1> f 'int (int)'
  |-ParmVarDecl 0x5aeaa90 <line:1:7, col:11> x 'int'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x5aead88 <col:14, line:4:1>
    |-DeclStmt 0x5aead10 <line:2:3, col:24>
    | `-VarDecl 0x5aeac10 <col:3, col:23> result 'int'
    |   `-ParenExpr 0x5aeacf0 <col:16, col:23> 'int'
    |     `-BinaryOperator 0x5aeacc8 <col:17, col:21> 'int' '/'
    |       |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x5aeacb0 <col:17> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
    |       | `-DeclRefExpr 0x5aeac68 <col:17> 'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x5aeaa90 'x' 'int'
    |       `-IntegerLiteral 0x5aeac90 <col:21> 'int' 42
    `-ReturnStmt 0x5aead68 <line:3:3, col:10>
      `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x5aead50 <col:10> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
        `-DeclRefExpr 0x5aead28 <col:10> 'int' lvalue Var 0x5aeac10 'result' 'int'
```

I know, nobody forbids to do whatever you want, but I looking for proper and well-known in compiler community way to do my specific semantic analysis. This question can be treated as asking for advice, not for solution.

Comment: I am not going to mark this as opinion based but I think it is. Pretty much every compiler stores meta data in the AST. Position is commonly stored, most statically typed languages have typed syntax trees that store type information. Some even store the hash (see Scala's `TASTy` or Unison). I am not sure if byte size is particularly useful as you can re-calculate it easily. As for the "proper" way to store this. There is no one answer as it highly highly depends on the language the compiler is written in and what it supports

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to store semantic information in the tree, you'll have to decide what, concretely, to store.   If you have 5 useful things, you'll be tempted to add those 5 things in a struct which is part of the node.

Having gotten that to be useful, you'll be tempted over time to add more.  Whatever you've attached to the AST node will keep growing because you'll find more and more things to add.   What you'll end up with is a giant "struct" (or class or whatever).

We call these things God classes.  You don't want them.

Better, for each semantic analysis, to keep its information isolated.

We (my company Semantic Designs) use associations (in our multilingual DMS Toolkit) to do this, driven by a hash code associated with the AST node.

Then you can have as many types of semantic information as you please, associated only with the nodes that need it, only when you need it.

It also allows you to have multiple threads processing the tree.  They can, be design either share the associations, or build thread-specific instances as needed.

This has held up nicely over the 25 year lifespan of DMS, over many languages and many, many semantically driven tools.